How to find all perfect squares such that their base 9 representation is all 1s?
I am working on solving all of the problems in from the Macalester College Problems of the Week that are available in this archive, and am currently working on MacPOW 1114:

Squares of 1
Find all perfect squares whose base 9 representation consists of only 1s.

Here is my current progress on this:

First of all, we can see that 1 is the only trivial solution - there of course have to be other non-trivial solutions.

So really our problem here is finding square numbers of the form$$\sum_{n=0}^k9^n$$however I'm not really sure about how I should go about finding square numbers of that form. I guess that if I replace 9 with $x$, then the problem really is equivalent to finding polynomials $p(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\cdots+1$ such that$$p(x)^2=x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}+x^{2n-2}+\cdots+1$$although my question is: How do I solve this problem? I'm not sure what to do from here, so any help is appreciated.

Do you know a formula for the sum of a finite geometric series?

No, even if you prove there is no polynomial square root of $x^n + x^{n-1} + \cdots + 1$, that still won't establish that some particular value of $x$ and $n$ doesn't have an integer square root.  For instance, $x^2 + 9x + 6$ is not the square of a polynomial, but $196 = 10^2 + 9\cdot 10 + 6$ is certainly a square.

@GEdgar It's $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ where r is the common ratio and a is the coefficient, why?

Does this answer your question? How many squares in base $9$ consist of only ones - found using a site search.

Why?  Because $\sum_{n=0}^k9^n$ is a geometric series.
